# Does tedious module for node.js have any function for preventing sql injection?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-injection, tedious

For your information, I'm working on preventing sql injection using Microsoft Azure & tedious module.

I saw a function called "escape" on mysql module, but I'm not sure if the similar function is in tedious module or not.

Comment: http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Escaping is an ancient technique that's annoying to use and also error prone (it's somewhat easy to forget a variable or escape it twice—and it's not uncommon to see the *wrong* escaping function being used). Any decent database library written in the last decade must support prepared statements or be dropped.

The side menu of the [Tedious site](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/) features a prominent [Using Parameters](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/) first level entry that covers this:

> here is support for parameterised statements, and using parameters
>   when calling procedures.
>
> Input parameters are added to a Request using
>   `Request.addParameter()`, and output parameters are added using
>   `Request.addOutputParameter()` Parameter names
>
> In T-SQL, parameter names are identified by being prefixed with an
>   '@'.
>
> ```
> select id from address where first_name = @name and age > @age
> ```
>
> The parameters names used in this API do not include the '@'.
>
> ```
> request.addParameter('name', ..., ...);
> request.addParameter('age', ..., ...);
> ```

They could have provided a less verbose syntax but it should get the job done.